# ODE: alternate two functions in a timeline

Tags: r, loops, ode

I am working with ODE and I want to alternate `rk(x, times1, func1, parms)` and `rk(x, times2, func2, parms)` 20 times accumulating (updating) the state variable, so each new run starts with the result of the previous run. Thanks in advance!

```
require(deSolve)
func1 <- function(t, x, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(parms, x)),{

    drN  = k*(No-N) - (Np+Tp) + r*(Np+Tp)  
    drNp = L1*Np - r*Np - (s+k)*Np
    drTp = L2*Tp - r*Tp - (s+k)*Tp
    res <- c(drN, drNp, drTp)
    list(res)
  })
}

func2 <- function(t, x, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(parms, x)),{

    drN  = k*(No-N) - (Np+Tp) + r*(Np+Tp) + 1  
    drNp = L1*Np - r*Np - (s+k)*Np + 1
    drTp = L2*Tp - r*Tp - (s+k)*Tp + 1
    res <- c(drN, drNp, drTp) + 1
    list(res)
  })
}

times1  <- seq(0, 200, length = 200)
times2  <- seq(0, 20, length = 200)

parms  <- c(L1=0.4, L2=0.3, No=1.3, k=0.5, r=0.3, s=0.2)
x <- c(N = 0.4, Np = 0.01, Tp = 0.01)


out <- rk(x, times1, func1, parms) + rk(x, times2, func2, parms) +
  rk(x, times1, func1, parms) + rk(x, times2, func2, parms) +
  rk(x, times1, func1, parms) + rk(x, times2, func2, parms) +
  rk(x, times1, func1, parms) + rk(x, times2, func2, parms) #this is what I tried, but failed


plot (out)
```

Comment: I don't get the point. You can run `rk(x, times1, func1, parms)` and `rk(x, times2, func2, parms)` 20 times and it will always be the same result. 

Do you want to update the state variable `x` after each run? 
if not, you can multiply one run of `rk(...)` with 20 (for `times1` and `times2`)

Comment: Hi! I want to alternate rk(x, times1, func1, parms) and rk(x, times2, func2, parms) 20 times accumulating (updating) the state variable, so each new run starts with the result of the previous run

Comment: This is not involved in your code!

Comment: you were right actually... thanks! then I have the problem that I dont know how to alternate tow ODE functions updating the state variables with each run...

Comment: After each function call `out <- rk(x, times1, func1, parms)` `x <- out[200,2:4]]` to use the last row of your output
This `x` is now the new x for for the next run `out <- rk(x, times2, func2, parms)`.

And I would not tot up all the results but save them in a list and then combine them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my quick solution, not elegant, but working:

```
out_list <- list()
combined <- matrix(data = c(0,0,0,0), ncol = 4)
time_sum <- 0

for(i in seq(1,20,2)){

  out1 <- rk(x, times1, func1, parms) 

  out_list[[i]] <- out1
  x <- out1[200,2:4]

  ## sum up timeline
  time_sum <- c(time_sum, time_sum[length(time_sum)]+out1[,"time"])

  out2 <- rk(x, times2, func2, parms) 

  out_list[[i+1]] <- out2
  x <- out2[200,2:4]

  ## sum up timeline
  time_sum <- c(time_sum, time_sum[length(time_sum)]+out2[,"time"])

  ## combine both ODEs
  combined <- rbind(combined, rbind(out1, out2))

}

## remove first column and "time" from combined matrix
combined <- combined[-1,]
time_sum <- time_sum[-1]

## plot ----
matplot(time_sum,combined[,2:4], type = "l")
```

Regards,
J_F